# How to represent average speed problem as rational equation?

Tags: physics

> A driver went $200$ km. For the first $100$ km of the trip, the driver traveled at
> a speed of $40$ km/h. For the second half of the trip, the driver traveled at a
> speed of $60$ km/h. What was the driver’s average speed for the entire trip?

I used the average speed formula which is $\text{speed}_\text{average} = \dfrac{\text{total distance}}{\text{total time}}$

& got $\dfrac{200}{\dfrac{100}{40}+\dfrac{100}{60}}$

which resulted into an average speed of $48$ km/h.

My problem is the way I solved the problem, our topic is rational equations & I don't know how to make it like that with a variable. Does anyone have a clue on how to make a rational equation out of this?

Comment: The speed formula looks very much like a rational equation. Not sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: If you really want to make it "prettier", you can write
$$
\frac{200}{\frac{100}{40} + \frac{100}{60}} =
 \frac{200}{\frac{300}{120} + \frac{200}{120}} = 
 \frac{200}{\left(\frac{5 00}{120} \right)} = \ldots
$$

Comment: is there a way to have a representation for it so that the rational equation has a variable?